# Images in sites/default/files are not allowed to be seen anymore

Tags: 7, media, wysiwyg

Today I realized, that all images, that are located in sites/default/files/fields may not be accessed anymote, neither are they shown in my articles nor may I see them in the browser (e.g. http://daniel-stein.com/node/210#). All I get is a 403 - no permission - error. The folder and the files within are all set to 744 (and I also tested 777). I have not found any permissions I could adjust and I am not sure when this started or what I changed in that moment. Maybe it was around the time I changed from buedit to ckedit but the switch back was also useless.

Comment: have you checked the settings for your public files folder path in admin/config/media/file-system? It may not be set to sites/default/files

Comment: Public is set to sites/default/files - so I think it is correct...

Comment: is the .htaccess file present in sites/default/files?

Comment: Yes, there is one (and I have not modified it).

Comment: I notice that the image referenced is created as a derivative image (ie in a styles directory). Have you verified that the generated image is present at that location?

Comment: Ah, I wasn't aware of this, thanks. But yes, the referenced image is http://daniel-stein.com/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/field/image/640px-Hipster_with_bike.jpg is indeed present in that directory - although the rights were different here (folder: 775, file:664)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/19615/discussion-between-daniel-and-autopoietic).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I found a solution that worked for me.

In the process of investigating in this problem and the fact why it does not appear on other Drupal installations I have running on the same server I messed up the permission settings on my server. In order to reorder things, I installed the module https://www.drupal.org/project/security_review - it produces a list with potential security problems of your Drupal installation. I worked myself down the list solving the issues one by one. I am not sure if this was the point in the beginning but after I changed the permissions of the .htaccess-file in sites/default/files to 444 (readonly) suddenly my images were accessible again.

For your reference, here are a lot of other approaches you can try if the one I presented is not helping: https://www.drupal.org/node/1170440